# Starting and stopping Mongrel service over SSH on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssh, ruby-on-rails, cygwin, mongrel

I have a Rails app running under mongrel as a windows service on a Windows Server 2003 installation.

I'd like to automate deploying new versions of the app from my Ubuntu dev server.

Cygwin is installed on the Windows server for this purpose. I can connect in via ssh and `net stop servicename` but `net start servicename` doesn't bring the service up. My initial thoughts were maybe there are windows-specific paths involved in mongrel::service and under a cygwin environment it chokes?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it using a different command line util like sc.exe?

Answer (score 0):

Does the service start when you try it through the services GUI/MMC?  If so then perhaps you need to take a second look to verify that your using the right service name.

Comment: It works fine via GUI or when I "net start|stop" from cmd.exe. And, the service stops when I run "net stop" over SSH. It's just "net start" over SSH that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same problem I've had with sshd, but make sure you only have 1 cygwin dll laying around your system. If there is more than one in the path it might be causing problems. With sshd I couldn't even get the service to start.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but I don't think that's what's going on. This is the first time Cygwin or anything even remotely related to Cygwin has been installed on the machine, and sshd itself is running without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying a stand-alone SSH server for Windows, like [VShell](http://www.vandyke.com/products/vshell/index.html) or [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/).

I remember using [copSSH](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh) a while ago with good results.